# Hourly systemd timer for work hours when end of day is after midnight?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I would like to run a systemd service hourly from 9am in the morning to 1am at night (one hour past midnight local time).

As a starting point I can use a time specification similar to the following to run a timer from 9am to 11pm: `"*-*-* 09..23:00:00"`

I can test it with:

```
systemd-analyze calendar "*-*-* 09..23:00:00"
```

This appears to work correctly based on the output.

However, when I try something like the following it does not work:

```
systemd-analyze calendar "*-*-* 09..01:00:00"
Failed to parse calendar specification '*-*-* 08..01:00:00': Invalid argument
```

I have tried a lot of variations of the following without success yet:

```
systemd-analyze calendar "*-*-* 00..01:00:00,09..23:00:00"
```

I think I'm close, but I can't get the notation right. Have referred to https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.time.7

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution looks like this:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00..01,09..23:00:00
```

You cannot mix hour and minutes in the notation, which is why this form does not work:

```
"*-*-* 00..01:00:00,09..23:00:00"
```

The hourly range needs to be defined before specifying minutes. In this case the hourly range is:

```
00..01,09..23
```